# How to import migrated Aperture library from Apple Photos to Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, apple-aperture, import, iphoto

I'm a bit late at migrating to Lightroom. I was an iPhoto user, then an Aperture user, and when Apple killed Aperture, I switched to Apple Photos. I regret my decision.

**Apple Photos doesn't meet my needs, and I'd like to switch to Lightroom.** Moreover, I want to preserve as much organizational information (ratings, keywords, metadata, labels, face tags) as possible. I think this possible with Adobe plug-ins for *iPhoto→Lightroom* and *Aperture→Lightroom*, but, as far as I can tell, Adobe hasn't made any import plug-in for Apple Photos. Fortunately, I still have access to my old Aperture library from before I migrated it to Apple Photos.

**Can you help me cobble together an import plan that optimizes the amount of organization data that are preserved?** These are the resources at my disposal:

1. `Aperture Library 1.aplibrary` (7.3 MB), which I only include for completeness. It's `created` and `last opened` timestamps are within six minutes of each other two years ago. Its existence seems consistent with [other users' experiences](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7003322?start=0&tstart=0).
2. `Aperture Library 2.migratedaplibrary` (118.41 GB), which was born out of my ill-conceived *Aperture→Photos* migration and appears to be actively modified by Photos yet still readable by Aperture. The *Aperture→Lightroom* plug-in does not want to import a `.migratedaplibrary`; it wants an `.aplibrary`. I tried to simply rename this to `Aperture Library 2.aplibrary`, and the plugin didn't like that either.
3. `iPhoto Library.photolibrary` (7.4 MB), which I only include for completeness. It's `created` and `last opened` timestamps are within six minutes of each other two years ago.
4. `Photos Library.photoslibrary` (73.45 GB), the main file that gets used by Photos on a day-to-day basis.
5. A backup folder full of Aperture reference image files (195 GB)

I would usually be able to tell where all my photos reside by how big each library is, but since Apple Photos stores so much in the iCloud, I can't be completely sure. I have not downloaded all originals to my iMac, but I can.

I imagine the best outcome would be to import my old Aperture library (with metadata), import my current Photos library (photos only), and magically deduplicate between them. I imagine this is easy to screw up. The details scare me, and I'm not sure whether I can massage my migrated Aperture into being eligible for use with the Adobe *Aperture→Lightroom* import plug-in.

Comment: I'm in a similar position. I'm considering getting Lightroom and not doing any migration. If I need photos from any of my old libraries, I'll just run Aperture if I need them. That seems easier than trying to reimport everything (especially with no adjustments), or export everything from Aperture as JPEGs with adjustments. It's just not worth the time.

Comment: Ugh. Not what I was hoping to hear. I would be content losing all of my metadata in Photos as long as I can keep my metadata from Aperture. Reverting to a non-migrated Aperture library would be enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In May 2019, Adobe published a free Lightroom plugin for Mac to help people migrate from Aperture and iPhoto libraries. It does exactly what you want. [Migrate from Aperture to Lightroom Classic on macOS](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/import-iphoto.html).

Here is what it includes:

> METADATA

```
Flags
Star Ratings
Keywords
GPS Data
Faces: Face naming tags are mapped to keywords
Rejects: Files designated as Rejects in Aperture are imported into Collections > From Aperture > Photos Rejected in Aperture
Info Panel metadata that can be entered in the Info panel (i.e. IPTC)
Hidden Files: Files designated as Hidden in iPhoto are imported into Collections > From iPhoto > Photos Hidden in iPhoto
Aperture Color Labels: Color Labels are mapped to keywords: Red, Orange, and so on, including support for custom label names
```

> ORGANIZATION

```
Aperture Stacking: Stacks information is mapped to keywords: Aperture Stack 1, Aperture Stack 2, and so on
Aperture project/folder/album hierarchies are mapped as closely as possible into Lightroom Classic collection sets and collections
iPhoto events/folders/albums are mapped as closely as possible into Lightroom Classic collection sets and collections
Aperture Versions translate into Virtual Copies in Lightroom Classic (without adjustments)
```

> EDITS

```
You can choose to import Full-Size JPEG Previews of your edited images from Aperture/iPhoto, if they are up-to-date - This option is off by default. Lightroom Classic can automatically stack the preview with the original photo.
    Full-Size JPEG Previews generated from files that have settings don't include metadata that has been applied to the master (keywords, star ratings, flags, GPS data).
    Full-Size JPEG Previews are duplicated if imported first by the same iPhoto library and then later from a Library upgraded from iPhoto to Aperture (due to a difference in filename).
```